# Visual Studio is stuck at loading desinger, and it's not loading the form design

Tags: visual-studio

The problem happens when I load one of my team project solution it keeps loading none stop, but when I open a new project it loads normally and I can do whatever loading designer

[image: 1]

I've been looking for days but they only thing I can find is when you get error loading massage

and this is the code I can see not the one my team mate wrote

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Panel2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.MenuStrip2 = New System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip()
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.المديرToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.المساعدToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.الانظمةToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.التعليماتToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.الاسسToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.القراراتToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.الاتفاقياتToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.الطلبةToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.الموظفينToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.القظاياToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.قضايااداريةToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.قضاياالطلبةToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.قضاياالموظفينToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.تسجيلخروجToolStripMenuItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem()
        Me.PictureBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.Panel2.SuspendLayout()
        Me.MenuStrip2.SuspendLayout()
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Panel2
        '
        Me.Panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.Panel2.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
        Me.Panel2.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.Panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top
        Me.Panel2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 36)
        Me.Panel2.Name = "Panel2"
        Me.Panel2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1156, 123)
        Me.Panel2.TabIndex = 1
        '
        'Label2
        '
        Me.Label2.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.Label2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.2!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 17)
        Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
        Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(63, 23)
        Me.Label2.TabIndex = 1
        Me.Label2.Text = "Label2"
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
        Me.Label1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial Black", 36.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(206, 17)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(758, 85)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Label1.Text = "جامعة مؤتة - الشؤون القانونية"
        Me.Label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter
        '
        'MenuStrip2
        '
        Me.MenuStrip2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.MenuStrip2.ImageScalingSize = New System.Drawing.Size(20, 20)
        Me.MenuStrip2.Items.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem, Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem, Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem, Me.القظاياToolStripMenuItem, Me.قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem, Me.تسجيلخروجToolStripMenuItem})
        Me.MenuStrip2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.MenuStrip2.Name = "MenuStrip2"
        Me.MenuStrip2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1156, 36)
        Me.MenuStrip2.TabIndex = 3
        Me.MenuStrip2.Text = "MenuStrip2"
        '
        'HfdhToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem, Me.المديرToolStripMenuItem, Me.المساعدToolStripMenuItem, Me.المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem})
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.Name = "HfdhToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(158, 32)
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.Text = "معلومات الدائرة"
        Me.HfdhToolStripMenuItem.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.TextBeforeImage
        '
        'الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right
        Me.الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem.Name = "الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(241, 32)
        Me.الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem.Text = "الهيكل التنظيمي "
        '
        'المديرToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.المديرToolStripMenuItem.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right
        Me.المديرToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.المديرToolStripMenuItem.Name = "المديرToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.المديرToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(241, 32)
        Me.المديرToolStripMenuItem.Text = "المدير"
        '
        'المساعدToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.المساعدToolStripMenuItem.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right
        Me.المساعدToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.المساعدToolStripMenuItem.Name = "المساعدToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.المساعدToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(241, 32)
        Me.المساعدToolStripMenuItem.Text = "المساعد"
        '
        'المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right
        Me.المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem.Name = "المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(241, 32)
        Me.المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem.Text = "مهام الدائرة"
        '
        'القوانينToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right
        Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.الانظمةToolStripMenuItem, Me.التعليماتToolStripMenuItem, Me.الاسسToolStripMenuItem, Me.القراراتToolStripMenuItem, Me.الاتفاقياتToolStripMenuItem})
        Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem.Name = "القوانينToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(90, 32)
        Me.القوانينToolStripMenuItem.Text = "القوانين"
        '
        'الانظمةToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.الانظمةToolStripMenuItem.Name = "الانظمةToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.الانظمةToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(224, 32)
        Me.الانظمةToolStripMenuItem.Text = "الانظمة"
        '
        'التعليماتToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.التعليماتToolStripMenuItem.Name = "التعليماتToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.التعليماتToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(224, 32)
        Me.التعليماتToolStripMenuItem.Text = "التعليمات"
        '
        'الاسسToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.الاسسToolStripMenuItem.Name = "الاسسToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.الاسسToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(224, 32)
        Me.الاسسToolStripMenuItem.Text = "الأسس"
        '
        'القراراتToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.القراراتToolStripMenuItem.Name = "القراراتToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.القراراتToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(224, 32)
        Me.القراراتToolStripMenuItem.Text = "القرارات"
        '
        'الاتفاقياتToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.الاتفاقياتToolStripMenuItem.Name = "الاتفاقياتToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.الاتفاقياتToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(224, 32)
        Me.الاتفاقياتToolStripMenuItem.Text = "الاتفاقيات"
        '
        'اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.الطلبةToolStripMenuItem, Me.الموظفينToolStripMenuItem})
        Me.اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem.Name = "اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(114, 32)
        Me.اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem.Text = "اعرف حقك"
        '
        'الطلبةToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.الطلبةToolStripMenuItem.Name = "الطلبةToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.الطلبةToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(224, 32)
        Me.الطلبةToolStripMenuItem.Text = "الطلبة"
        '
        'الموظفينToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.الموظفينToolStripMenuItem.Name = "الموظفينToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.الموظفينToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(224, 32)
        Me.الموظفينToolStripMenuItem.Text = "الموظفين"
        '
        'القظاياToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.القظاياToolStripMenuItem.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right
        Me.القظاياToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.قضايااداريةToolStripMenuItem, Me.قضاياالطلبةToolStripMenuItem, Me.قضاياالموظفينToolStripMenuItem})
        Me.القظاياToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.القظاياToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.القظاياToolStripMenuItem.Name = "القظاياToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.القظاياToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(85, 32)
        Me.القظاياToolStripMenuItem.Text = "القضايا"
        '
        'قضايااداريةToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.قضايااداريةToolStripMenuItem.Name = "قضايااداريةToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.قضايااداريةToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(232, 32)
        Me.قضايااداريةToolStripMenuItem.Text = "قضايا  ادارية"
        '
        'قضاياالطلبةToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.قضاياالطلبةToolStripMenuItem.Name = "قضاياالطلبةToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.قضاياالطلبةToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(232, 32)
        Me.قضاياالطلبةToolStripMenuItem.Text = "قضايا الطلبة"
        '
        'قضاياالموظفينToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.قضاياالموظفينToolStripMenuItem.Name = "قضاياالموظفينToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.قضاياالموظفينToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(232, 32)
        Me.قضاياالموظفينToolStripMenuItem.Text = "قضايا الموظفين"
        '
        'قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right
        Me.قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem.Name = "قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(151, 32)
        Me.قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem.Text = "قرارات المحاكم "
        '
        'تسجيلخروجToolStripMenuItem
        '
        Me.تسجيلخروجToolStripMenuItem.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10.2!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.تسجيلخروجToolStripMenuItem.Name = "تسجيلخروجToolStripMenuItem"
        Me.تسجيلخروجToolStripMenuItem.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(112, 32)
        Me.تسجيلخروجToolStripMenuItem.Text = "تسجيل خروج"
        '
        'PictureBox1
        '
        Me.PictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.PictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom

        Me.PictureBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 156)
        Me.PictureBox1.Name = "PictureBox1"
        Me.PictureBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1156, 524)
        Me.PictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        Me.PictureBox1.TabIndex = 4
        Me.PictureBox1.TabStop = False
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(8.0!, 20.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1156, 680)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Panel2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.MenuStrip2)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "home page"
        Me.Panel2.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.Panel2.PerformLayout()
        Me.MenuStrip2.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.MenuStrip2.PerformLayout()
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents Panel2 As Panel
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As Label
    Friend WithEvents MenuStrip2 As MenuStrip
    Friend WithEvents HfdhToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents الهيكلالتنظيميToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents المديرToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents المساعدToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents المهامالتيتقومبهاالدائرةToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents القوانينToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents الانظمةToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents التعليماتToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents الاسسToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents القراراتToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents الاتفاقياتToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox1 As PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents اعرفحقكToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents الطلبةToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents الموظفينToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents القظاياToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents قضايااداريةToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents قضاياالطلبةToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents قضاياالموظفينToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents قراراتالمحاكمToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
    Friend WithEvents Label2 As Label
    Friend WithEvents تسجيلخروجToolStripMenuItem As ToolStripMenuItem
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using 2022, but the solution it 2017.

Answer (score -1):

Simply click in the window... (until ms fix it)